# my columns are too large when compared to sample project

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and I am following along a tutorial. In the tutorial, there are 5 columns underneath the image. I am doing exactly the same thing as the tutorial, yet my columns are appearing much larger. Why is this? How can I get them to be smaller, similar to the tutorial sample? First one is sample, second one is how mine looks.

[image]

[image]

**html**

```css
.stat-numbers .col-1,
.stat-numbers .col-2 {
  background: rgba(16, 255, 0, 0.15);
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.stat-numbers .col-1.transparent,
.stat-numbers .col-2.transparent {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row stat-numbers">
  <div class="col-2 transparent"></div>
  <div class="col-2">B</div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="icon">D</div>
    <div class="points">18</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 transparent">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">B</div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="icon">E</div>
    <div class="points">18</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="icon">R</div>
    <div class="points">18</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 transparent"></div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: The code you posted in your question doesn't match your image. Your code is missing a Bootstrap container, e.g. `<div class="container">`

Comment: Are you able to set up a codepen so we can have a play around with it? I can't see what's wrong.